# Rails 5 with Font-Awesome and Bootstrap error

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I'm building my first rails application, and I'd like to integrate both bootstrap and font-awesome. I managed to get the application working properly using just bootstrap, but when I attempted to incorporate font-awesome as well, I either get the error: file to import not found or unreadable:font-awesome, or the webpage shows up, but only renders using just html, without any of the css or bootstrap styling that I've added. I then simply decided not to use font-awesome, but after attempting to remove it, the application just renders with just the html, and none of the added bootstrap styling.

Here is my application.css.scss:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_font-awesome
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/theme";
@import "font-awesome";
```

I searched through some other issues that were similar to this one - I saw that for rails engines, if you did @import "font-awesome.css" that seemed to work. However, I'm not building a rails engine, and attempting this did not resolve the issue.

I've included gem 'font-awesome-rails' in my gemfile, and ran a bundle install as well.

Lastly, I'm using rails 5.0.0.1, and font-awesome-rails 4.7.0.0

Any ideas what is wrong? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Add in Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.7.0'
```

And then `bundle install`

Create a file in `/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_overrides.css.scss` and add this line:-

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
```

Example to use font awesome, in the view:

```
<%= icon('flag') %>
```

Please check the link for more usages on [font awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass)

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I tried this, I got an actioncontroller error when I went to localhost:3000 -> Sass syntax error, undefined variable $gray-light. I'm assuming that this is because I'm somehow failing to import bootstrap?